# flash messages cakephp 2.7 and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I integrate "Twitter Bootstrap" with my little  CakePHP project, I have 2 questions:

1) There is a way to use the standards flash messages? (because after the integration the alerts are not working anymore)

2)How can I use [this](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/) Js alert? (in vers 2.7 the flash messages were changed from

```
<?php $this->Session->setFlash("Flash Message");?>
```

to

```
<?php $this->Flash->success(__('Flash Message'));?>
```

and I can't find the way to do that)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`FlashComponent` provides far more flexibility than what `Session->setFlash()` does.

Now you are not bound to a single method, but can implement as many different flash 'magic' methods as you wish.

To be able to flash a custom flash message with

```
$this->Flash->success(__('Flash Message'));?>
```

You need to create an element in

```
app/View/Elements/Flash/success.ctp
```

with the appropriate HTML/javascript template.

You have more information in the [Cookbook 2.x: Setting Flash Messages](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/flash.html#setting-flash-messages)

Comment: It helped me. Thanks. And the JS alert is possible? How can I work with it.?

Answer (score 0):

// please include any jquery min js  Create a file called success.ctp in app/View/Elements/ folder

```
<div class="success_msg alert">
<a href="#" class="close">x</a>
<?php echo $message; ?>
</div>

// add css :- 
.alert {

border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 15px;}

.success_msg {
background-color: #dff0d8;
border-color: #d6e9c6;
color: #3c763d;}


.close{   text-decoration :none;
 float: right;}



// Add script :-
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#content .close').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().fadeOut();
   return false; });


  $('.alert').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000).fadeOut();
 });


// Use this anywhere in your controller actions,
 $this->Session->setFlash('You have successfully logged   
         in','success');
return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
```

Comment: Not sure this is what the OP is requesting. He wants to use the [Bootstrap Notify plugin](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/), and `FlashComponent` instead of `SessionComponent`.